# HttpClient Post session issue? How do I know if session has been created?

Tags: android, post, httpclient

This is a follow up question of [Sending html commands over httpclient android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550593/sending-html-commands-over-httpclient-android) , I have successfully POSTed to the server and recieved 200 code but when I attempt to move to another page it does not recognize that I have logged in. I am wondering if it is a session issue or if i need to follow the redirect after the POST. How would I go about following a redirect? Again any help is greatly appreciated. Here is a simple HttpClient / POST app I created from examples in order to help me quickly test any changes.

```
public class HttpClientTest extends Activity{

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button btnFetch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView txtResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.content);
    final Button login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);


    btnFetch.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            getRequest(txtResult);
        }
    });

    login.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            try {
                login(txtResult);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void getRequest(TextView txtResult){
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://gc.gamestotal.com/i.cfm?f=com_empire&cm=3");
    try{
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        txtResult.setText(Parser.request(response));
    }catch(Exception ex){
        txtResult.setText("Failed!");
    }
}

public void login(TextView txtResult) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException{
    String action = "i.cfm?&1028&p=login&se=4";
    String yourServer = "http://gc.gamestotal.com/";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(yourServer + action);
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nic", "user"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("server", "4"));
    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8");
    post.setEntity(entity);

    try{
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        txtResult.setText(response.getEntity().toString());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        txtResult.setText("Failed!");
    }
}
```

}

I first press the login button on the UI which gives me the Http/1.1 200 OK response code, but when I press the btnFetch button which sends me to a page in which you must but logged in to access, I get the not logged in page. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to ask this question of whoever wrote the Web app you are accessing. Only they can tell you how they want you do what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I was afraid of such. Thank you for the response.

Comment: May be some cookie issues.. Please check

Comment: I'm looking into figuring out the cookie, I am starting to think it may be a "Referer" issue. I will try editing the headers to mimic exactly Firefox aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and many examples later I have finally managed to login to the site I was attempting. Apparently It was an issue with me not consuming the entity from the response, ie the cookies. I created a simple activity who's main purpose is to GET and POST to the site then spit out the result into LogCat. Perhaps this may help others.

```
public class HttpClientTest extends Activity{

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request;
HttpEntity entity;
List<Cookie> cookies;
HttpResponse response;
HttpPost post;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        getRequest();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("My Activity", "Failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void getRequest() throws Exception
{
    final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    request = new HttpGet("http://some.site.com/");
    response = client.execute(request);
    entity = response.getEntity();
    Log.d(TAG, "Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
    if(entity != null)
    {
        entity.consumeContent();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Initial set of cookies:");

    cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty())
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "None");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<cookies.size(); i++)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "- " + cookies.get(i));
        }
    }
    String action = "i.cfm?&1028&p=login&se=4";
    String yourServer = "http://some.site.com/";
    post = new HttpPost(yourServer + action);

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nic", "username"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("server", "4"));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));


    response = client.execute(post);
    entity = response.getEntity();

    Log.d(TAG, "Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
    if(entity != null){
        entity.consumeContent();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Post logon cookies:");
    cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty())
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "None");
    } 
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "- " + cookies.get(i));
        }
    }


    request = new HttpGet("http://some.site.com/i.cfm?f=com_empire&cm=3");

    response = client.execute(request);
    Log.d(TAG, "Check for login: " + Parser.request(response));
    if(entity != null)
    {
        entity.consumeContent();
    }

}

}
```

the last log, Log.d(TAG, "Check for login: " + Parser.request(response)); prints out the html of the site by going through a parser class, which I used to verify that it was infact a page that required successful login

Answer (score 4):

I know, quite a little bit late, but I also come across this posting and I want the link to this answere here: [Android session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224913/android-session-management) which says that you should reuse your `HttpClient` which handles Session Management, ie. make `HttpClient` static and instantiate it only once. 
But I dont know if this is the whole truth for your requirements. For me it was.

Cheers!