# Sessions in android

Tags: android, session

I am trying to create a list of certaing objects, so i can see it anytime and anywhere. So i was wondering if there is any way to have some information in an Android activity, and sees it in the other activities just like the Session[] in asp.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Android Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

SharedPreferences prefs =
     getSharedPreferences("myPreferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("email", "test@email.com");
editor.putString("name", "Test");
editor.commit();
```

And to get the data use this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs =
     getSharedPreferences("myPreferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String email= prefs.getString("email", "default_email@email.com");
```

Comment: But, in the case I wanna use a list of objects creates for me, instead of "putString", how would it be, with serialize? ....

Comment: If you want to store an object, you could transform it to an JsonObject with Gson, but remember that you shouldnt store to much information here. See this example: http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com.es/2011/07/store-and-get-object-in-android-shared.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Android [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class.  It's essentially a singleton with the lifetime of your app.

Or as others have suggested, use Shared Preferences to a) persist things across `Activities` and b) persist things across "sessions".

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224913/android-session-management) or simple [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can push all your shared information in a static object.

The best way to do it is to create a singleton. Here is a sample: 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html